# Can not return pointer array in the struct

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I am new to C++. below is my code. I saw a correct array in "setValue", but in "main", I can not get the right array value on strC. where did I miss?

```
template <int N>
struct strA{
    int *p;
};

template <int N>
strA<N> setValue(int n)
{
    strA<N> strB;
    int m[N];
    // pointer initialization
    strB.p=m;
    for (int i=0; i<N;i++)
    {
        strB.p[i]=i+n;
    }
    return strB;
}

int main(){
    const int N=3;
    strA<N> strC;
    strC=setValue<N> (5);
    for (int i=0; i<N;i++)
    {
        cout<< strC.p[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare an array in a function like `int m[n]` and then assign it to a pointer, this pointer after the function doesn’t point to nothing. You have to allocate a new area and point it with the strB.p pointer, do this in **setValue**

```
strB.p=new Int[n]
```

Comment: Dear helpers,  thank you so much for the prompt replies. now my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines in the `setValue` function is the problem:

```
int m[N];
strB.p=m;
```

The first defined `m` as a ***local*** variable. As such it will go out of scope and its lifetime will end as soon as the function returns (the variable `m` will in essence cease to exist).

The second line make `strB.p` point to the first elements of this array.

That means when the function returns the pointer will immediately become invalid, and using it in any way will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The natural solution is to either use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
template <int N>
struct strA{
    std::array<int, N> p;
};

template <int N>
strA<N> setValue(int n)
{
    strA<N> strB;
    for (int i=0; i<N;i++)
    {
        strB.p[i]=i+n;
    }
    return strB;
}
```

No temporary array needed.

---

Of course, you could just define a normal C-style array directly in the structure as well, and still no temporary array like `m` being needed:

```
template <int N>
struct strA{
    int p[N];
};
```